# Use function sets to group by row values

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

Hi How do i apply lappy() to the values in rows?

Lets say my dataset is

```
Name     value      month
SP        50       January
Mary      67       January
Justin    33       January

SP        45       February
Mary      37       February
Justin    53       February

SP        55       March
Mary      67       March
Justin    23       March
```

So if i need to find the sum of values for each month,
to get my out put as:

```
Month        Value
January       150
February      135
March         145
```

Currently i only know how to calculate this on the whole without the monthly separation as in:

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- tibble(Name = c("SP","Mary","Justin","SP","Mary","Justin","SP","Mary","Justin"),
            value = c(50,67,33,45,37,53,55,67,23),
            Month = c("January", "January", "February", "February","March","March"))
y <- data.frame(x,sum(x$value))
```

I do not know how to  get my desired outcome.
any idea how?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(value ~ Month, x, sum)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
   group_by(Month) %>%
   summarise(value = sum(value))
```

Comment: if my calculation gets complicated, say, multiple levels of calculations, will i still be able to use the same format?

Comment: @SPishere  With `dplyr`, it is more easier as you can chain `%>%` the calculations with `mutate/summarise` and other functions `select/arrange` etc.  You can check the vignettes of tidyverse as it could be useful for you